# ZF AJAX drop down

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

How can i code for country state dropdowns in zend framework using ajax

I am not using zend_form class

using zend_helpers for building form .

any example code please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [ZendX_JQuery View Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zendx.jquery.view.html) in the ZF-Manual.
There should be something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Zend_Dojo_Data and Dojo dijit like dijit.form.FilteringSelect ?